# Enviar post a una API desde PHP con formato JSON

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Lo que me gustaría hacer es conectarme a una API que recibe parámetros en formato JSON y me gustaría que fuera mediante PHP. He visto que utilizan una llamada CURL, pero trato de implementarla pero no veo que mi hosting la tenga; entonces no se si exista la forma de hacerlo sin librerías.

ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO PHP

```
$data = array("name" => "juan", "message" => "hola");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('https://api');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: FDGFNGFHBDHFHSDFBDHBFH',
    'api-key: G2566FD99966GHH',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo las trazas que tengas del mensaje que se manda y de lo que se recibe en el servidor? ¿Puedes añadir también un mensaje mandado con postman o similar, que el servidor sí sea capaz de aceptar? Así podemos ver las diferencias de un mensaje correcto y el que te está fallando. A lo mejor mientras buscas esta información tu mismo ves dónde puede estar el fallo.

Comment: ya lo hice con postman y funciona esos son los parámetros que recibe la api pero no he podido integralo a php

Comment: Es por ver no solo los parámetros que le pasas, sino también la cabecera.

Comment: En `curl_init` debes poner la URL del hosting donde se procesarán los datos, no creo que `https://api` sea una URL de tu hosting ¿no? Y puedes implementar un manejo de errores, poniendo después del `curl_exec` algo así más o menos: `if(curl_errno($ch))
  {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

  }else{ print_r($result); }`

Comment: la url no es solo la puse de ejemplo

Comment: tampoco genera error no hace nada

Comment: En vez de `print_r` pon `var_dump($result);`

Comment: ya me sale este error Curl error: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Comment: Pues eso, parece que el certificado SSL de tu hosting está vencido, deberías consultarlo con el servicio técnico del hosting. Puedes ver los detalles del certificado haciendo clic en el candadito que aparece al lado de la URL en el navegador.

Comment: el certificado esta valido eso es lo que muestra en el navegador

Comment: ya vi que fue el problema hay que poner  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

Comment: gracias por su colaboración

Comment: Mmmm pero ten cuidado, revisa si tu certificado pasa esta validación: pon la URL de tu sitio aquí [https://www.digicert.com](https://www.digicert.com/) te dirá si hay algún problema con el certificado, si sale todo en verde. No deberías saltarte la verificación SSL, la petición cURL debería funcionar sin apagar `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, si tu hosting es serio, claro :)

Comment: verifique lo que me dices el esa pagina sale todo perfecto, el hosting que utilizo es una empresa importante

Comment: lei algo sobre eso y dan algunas soluciones como:   Using a cert with PHP’s cURL functions